# How to use Null-Conditional Operator to check for not Null?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Per example,

```
!_Worker?.StartWork() ?? "Work has started on current thread.";

Console.WriteLine(_Worker);

public string StartWork()
{
 //Do some work here.
}
```

To simplify instead of using C# 6.0,

```
if(!_Worker == null)
{
     _Worker = "Work has started on current thread.";
     Console.WriteLine(_Worker);
     StartWork();

}
```

Do these two examples equate?

I would expect the result to be write out "Work has started on current thread. " when _Worker = null.

Comment: In your second example `StartWork()` is not called as a method of `_Worker` so I highly doubt they can be equivalent (also you could just have tested this out?)

Comment: You seem to be mixing types in a strange way...Consider: what if you coded the simple line: `_Worker.StartWork()` -- that won't compile...

Comment: Also, what is `!_Worker` ? are you negating something ?

Comment: I don't think either of the samples is compiling. What is the type of `_Worker`? String? How would you call `StartWork` on an instance of `String`? What would `!_Worker` mean? there is no `!` operator on String ...

Comment: I feel like `if(!_Worker == null)` should be `if(_Worker != null)`

Comment: For about three months when I learned C# I wrote `if(!(x==null))` instead of `if(x!=null)`. Embarrassing. Not sure why nobody mentioned it.

Comment: This is some pseudo code, so to speak, I don't expect it to compile, I jus tneed to know if the Null Conditional Operator is the same as the if statement

Comment: how could someone decide whether two statements are equal, if none of them is valid, and their behaviour is therefore undefined. So in some sense they are indeed equal.

Comment: Let me simplify, Does `!_Worker?.StartWork()` equal `if(!Worker == null){ StartWork() }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null conditional operator was written to solve this problem:

```
if(someObject!=null 
    && someObject.ItsProperty!= null 
    && someObject.ItsProperty.PropertyOfThatThing!=null)
{
    theValueIWant == someObject.ItsProperty.PropertyOfThatThing.AnotherProperty;
}
```

Now we can write

```
theValueIWant = someObject?.ItsProperty?.PropertyOfThatThing?.AnotherProperty;
```

So it's not a way to check null - that already existed. `if(x==null)` or `if(x!=null)`. If that was the only need then this new operator wouldn't have been added. It's about accessing a member of a class that may be null.